# Error when trying to modify column data type in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, workbench

I'm trying to change the datatype of a column of one of my tables from TEXT to VARCHAR in my database. I use this simple query which seems correct to me:

```
ALTER TABLE my_database.my_table MODIFY `SalesRank` VARCHAR;
```

However I get the error: '' () is not valid input at this position.

What is wrong with my query? The column itself is completely empty. I'm using MYSQL Workbench.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_database.my_table MODIFY `SalesRank` VARCHAR(255);
```

You missed size of that column.
Just try above code.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that. Sometimes you're just blind! :D
Thank you!